# Why my ($i) indexing not working?

Tags: perl, indexing

my program is

```
#!\usr\bin\perl -w

my @one= ("sun", "moon", "star");
my $three="SON"; 
my $flag= 0;
my $tester_1=0 ; 
my $tester_2= 0;
my $i= 0;

push (@one, $three);

print @one; 
print join(" ", @one);

while (@one[$i]= $three) 
{
    #flag 1
    if (@one[$i] ne "moon"&& @one[$i] ne "star") 
    {
        $tester_1= 1; 
    }

    ##flag2 
    if ($i<= 99) 
    {
        $tester_2=1;
    }

    #real condition 
    if ($tester_1= 1)
    { 
        if ($tester_2= 1)   
        {
            print @one[$i];
            $i++; 
        }
    }
}
```

I run my program. The loop is running for infinite number of times. In flag 2 I set a condition that $i<= 99;, thus my program should stop after printing 100th SON according to me. But, for some reasons $i<= 99 is not working? What is the reason?

Comment: Why are you ignoring the warnings Perl is giving you?????

Comment: Also, always use `use strict;`

Answer (score 6):

You show having warnings enabled; your code produces warnings.  *Fix* them and you will have fixed your problem.  If you have trouble understanding the warnings, try adding `use diagnostics;`

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the problem is that you are using "=" in comparisons (e.g. `if($tester_1 = 1)` where it should be `if($tester_1 == 1)`). This kind of error appears on the warnings printed by Perl when you run your script.

You should also substitute:
`while (@one[$i]= $three)` by `while ($one[i] == $three)` and
`if (@one[$i] ne "moon"&& @one[$i] ne "star")` by `if ($one[$i] ne "moon"&& $one[$i] ne "star")`

Comment: and of course `while (@one[$i]= $three)` should be `while (@one[$i] == $three)`

Comment: no, it should be while ($one[1] eq $three). This Perl, she is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!\usr\bin\perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my @one= ("sun", "moon", "star");
my $three="SON"; 
my $flag= 0;
my $tester_1=0 ; 
my $tester_2= 0;
my $i= 0;

push (@one, $three);    
print @one,"\n"; 
print join(" ", @one),"\n";   

while ($one[$i] eq $three) 
{
 if ($one[$i] ne "moon"&& $one[$i] ne "star") 
 {
    $tester_1= 1; 
 }
 if ($i<= 99) 
 {
    $tester_2=1;
 }
 if ($tester_1 == 1)
 { 
    if ($tester_2 == 1)   
    {
        print $one[$i];
        $i++; 
    }
 }
}
```

This is the output I get for the script shown above :

```
sunmoonstarSON
sun moon star SON
```

Comment: @user1964232: Is this the output what you are looking for?